# Getting wireless N to work on Dell Vostro 3300?

Tags: wireless

I have a Dell Vostro 3300, which has a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless. 
The point is that I cannot make it work in N mode. NetwotkManager applet says I'm on 54 Mbit/s. Of course, my wireless router is N capable. I've double checked.
Anyone knows what to do?

Here is the output for `lspci -v`:

```
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0010
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at fbb00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, brcm80211
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I didn't know I needed to set WPA2 with AES encryption.
Anyway, this wireless card is not the best one around - is only capable of 72 Mb/s, which is the speed I have now after setting this encryption type...

Comment: Hmm. The laptop I'm on at the moment has a BCM4313 and it works beautifully with 2.6.39. As a side note, you don't want to use the `wl` (STA) driver. Blacklist it. `brcm80211` also now known as `brcmsmac` in newer kernels, is a much better, more stable driver. I didn't know about the speed limit. Why make a N device and then hobble it so it can only go at a quarter of its possible speed?!